# Allow users to access other users' data in couchdb

Tags: couchdb

I have my _users database secured, so a user can only access their own information. However, I'd like other users to be able to retrieve certain public information such as email addresses, real names, and phone numbers. What's the best way I can go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the info in the _local database, e.g. _local/userinfo.json. Of course you need to know the url of the other users.